# importjs extension fails in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed [vscode-import-js](https://github.com/dabbott/vscode-import-js) extension.

After followed instructions, I have the command `importjs` working via the command line.

But when I use the shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` to import in vscode. That raises a popup saying: `command 'importjs.fix' not found`

How to fix this? Or is there another extension which doing same?

Comment: You may not need any extension. VS Code has built-in support for [auto-import completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). Additionally, you can get `add missing import` quick fixes if you enable [type checking and semantic errors in your JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking).